# How do I strcmp specifically for newline in C?

Tags: c, debugging

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int counter1, counter2;
    char line[200] = ""; //store all words that don't need to be deleted
    char deleteWord[100]; //word that needs to be deleted
    char space;
    char word[100];
    scanf("%s", deleteWord);

    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", word);

        if (feof(stdin))
            break;
        // increment counter of total words
        ++counter1;
        if (strcmp(word, deleteWord) == 0) {
            // see if the word read in == delete word
            // increment counter of deleted words
            ++counter2;
        } else
        if (strcmp(word, " ") == 0) { // space is an actual space
            strcat(line, word);
            strcat(line, " ");
        } else
        if (strcmp(word, "\n")) { // space a new line \n
            strcat(line, word);
            strcat(line, "\n");
        }
    }

    printf("--NEW TEXT--\n%s", line);

    return 0;
}
```

In summary, my code is supposed to remove a user input string (one or more words) from another user input string (containing or not containing the word(s)) and produce the output. The code removes the word but it adds a newline per word for each iteration. I believe it is doing this because the expression for the second `else if` is always true. However, when I properly add the `strcmp` function for the second `else if` statement, the code does not produce an output at all (no compiler errors - just missing input). Why is this happening and how do I do a `strcmp` function for a newline?

Comment: Did you mean to have a `== 0` in the test of your last call to `strcmp()` ?

Comment: First `scanf()` doesn't read '\n' character into buffer. 2. `scanf()` will get you only one word, then statement & code "my code is supposed to remove a user input string (one or more words)" doesn't match. make up your mind. I.e what if user wants to remove two different words?

Comment: If you want to read a whole line of input consiting of several words, instead of a single word, then you should use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Instead of checking for `feof( stdin );`, it would probably be more appropriate to check the return value of `scanf`. Otherwise, if the last line before end-of-file does not end with a `'\n'`, the loop will terminate without processing the last line. Related, but does not completely apply here: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

Answer (score 0):

Your read the words with `scanf("%s", word)`, which poses these problems:

- all white space is ignored, so you cannot test for spaces nor newlines as you try to do in the loop, and you cannot keep track of line breaks.
- you should tell `scanf()` the maximum number of bytes to store into the destination array `word`, otherwise any word longer than 99 characters will cause a buffer overflow and invoke undefined behavior.
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` instead of callin `feof()` which might be true after the last word has been successfully read. You should simply write the loop as

  ```
    while (scanf("%99s", word) == 1) {
        // increment counter of total words
        ++counter1;
        ...
  ```
- you do not test if the words fit in the `line` array either, causing a buffer overflow if the words kept amount to more than 199 characters including separators.

To delete a specific word from a stream, you could read one line at a time and delete the matching words from the line:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char deleteWord[100]; //word that needs to be deleted
    char line[1000]; //store all words that don't need to be deleted

    printf("Enter the word to remove: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", deleteWord) != 1)
        return 1;

    // read and discard the rest of the input line
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;

    size_t len = strlen(deleteWord);
    printf("Enter the text: ");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        char *p = line;
        char *q;
        while ((p = strstr(p, deleteWord)) != NULL) {
            if ((p == line || isspace((unsigned char)p[-1]))
            &&  (p[len] == '\0' || isspace((unsigned char)p[len]))) {
                /* remove the word */
                memmove(p, p + len, strlen(p + len) + 1);
            } else {
                p += len;
            }
        }
        /* squeeze sequences of spaces as a single space */
        for (p = q = line + 1; *p; p++) {
            if (*p != ' ' || p[-1] != ' ')
                *q++ = *p;
        }
        *q = '\0';
        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```